# Removing duplicate data out of column datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I've looked all around and haven't found a answer :/

screenshot: http://prntscr.com/9257cg

I want that entry to only show up once and not stay there (the "to" column), basically remove the duplicates. Here is my update code

```
Private Sub datagridview1Update()

    'Remove rows if there are too many
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 9 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
    End If

    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(0).Value = ipfrom.ToString 'From Column, size at 125
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(1).Value = ipto.ToString  'To Column, size at 125
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(2).Value = destinationport.ToString
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(3).Value = sourceport.ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Are you asking for a "jagged" display - some rows without a "To"?

Comment: @Plutonix it's coming from my network adapter, its a packet capture program, it captures a ton of different "To" but it just keeps scrolling super fast I am wanting to limit down to one let me give you another screenshot: http://prntscr.com/925dn7 I would like for it to only show once per same "to" ip

Comment: if the data was in a datasource you could check for dupes and just not add a dupe to it.

Comment: @Plutonix datasource isn't that with access? this is live capture and populate from my network adapters.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with Access.  The data source for a `DataGridView` is simply an object that implements the `IList` interface.  That could be a `DataTable` populated from an Access database or some other database or some other type list, e.g. an array of POCOs.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Could you please explain how I could add it to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should loop through your DataGridView1's Rows to see if there is already an entry that matches the new data.  Add the new row if no match is found.  Also, you should only subtract one from the count of rows to keep correct ordering.

```
Private Sub datagridview1Update()

    Dim bolFoundMatch As Boolean = False
    Dim intCursor As Integer = 0

    Do Until bolFoundMatch OrElse intCursor = DataGridView1.Rows.Count

        If DataGridView1.Rows(intCursor).Cells(1).Value = ipto.ToString() Then

            bolFoundMatch = True

        End If

        intCursor += 1

    Loop

    If Not bolFoundMatch Then

        'Remove rows if there are too many
        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 9 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
        End If

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(0).Value = ipfrom.ToString 'From Column, size at 125
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(1).Value = ipto.ToString  'To Column, size at 125
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(2).Value = destinationport.ToString
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(3).Value = sourceport.ToString   

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I had it at 1 but it skips lines when I do like that for some reason. see: http://prntscr.com/925l2v